# Delete <br> in a div but not in children of the div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with some line-breaks which appear sometimes in a parent div. There are some other divs in the parent div. These divs also contain line-breaks. Is there a way to delete the line-breaks in the parent div and keep the line-breaks in the child divs?

note: It can be one line-break or more

Example:

```
    <div class="parent">
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="child1">
       Here <br>
       is <br>
       some <br>
       text <br>
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
       Here <br>
       is <br>
       some <br>
       text <br>
    </div>
    <div class="child3">
       Here <br>
       is <br>
       some <br>
       text <br>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I hope you know a solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using the direct child selector?

```
$("div.parent>br").remove();
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

If you just do `$("div.parent br")` it will select all decedents, not children only.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
$('.parent > br').remove();
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BVHRP/)

> From the [**MDN docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors):
>   A > E : Any E element that is a child of an A element